# How can I use flask mail to send message on a particular date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-mail

I was going through the flask mail documentation and had seen many videos of how to use flask mail. A form has 2 fields which will accept date and email address from the user. The owner of the application will send a "Hi" message on that particular date to the given mail address at any time within that day (or lets say at 6am on that day).
How to do this?

Comment: Please include the code you tried which is not working

Comment: use cron job, or serverless function to trigger at particular time or try use thread which invoke at a particular time (on thread i am not so sure)